# Implementing health check for a website hosting in GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, health-check, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have hosted a static website in the GCS bucket and another website in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). I have configured the load balancer with two backends having a reserved IP associated with the proper host and path rules. Both applications are working fine.

I have implemented the health check configuration inside the load balancer so that it can send an HTTP GET request to a request path. So far, the health check function is working for applications that are in GKE and I am getting proper logs but it's not working for the one that is inside the GCS bucket.

I found that as GCS is a vastly available managed Google service, there is no way to implement the health check the way I did. So please give me a suggestion on how to do that.

I am thinking of creating an external health check to ping the URL from somewhere else, so I can get logs related to a healthy URL or not. or is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Why do you need to monitor it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere In case the website goes down or if something is broken. I need to create Grafana alert from the health check logs. I have checked the cloud function and found it executes every 1 minute. Also checked UptimeRobot.. the same thing. It also monitors every 1 minute but I need to get the health check or ping response in seconds

Comment: Did you try to create a uptime check and not a health check?

Comment: How about scrape the metrics from the load balancer? It should have metrics to expose. Just scrape the metrics and configure your alerts.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i just checked that and found its min check frequency is 1 m but i need those in seconds

Comment: Oh, I see. Second is very intensive. You do not have this option on Google Cloud. You have to build something yourselves or use external tools. But why a such high uptime check? What's your use case that require such high availability?

Comment: Our application is in the production environment and demand is high that's why we wanna avoid any single chance of ignorance.